# WickedPDF generated with ActiveJob is creating a margin - how to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf, rails-activejob

I want to generate a PDF with ActiveJob, and then save it as an attachment to a record.

When I generate the PDF from a controller action, it looks fine:

[image]

When I move it to a background job, it is creating this margin around the pdf.

[image]

What is going on, and how can I remove the margin to make the contents cover the entire page?

CODE

Controller method that works as expected:

```
  def renderCatalogOnServer
      //declaring variables here -- removing to condense question
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "renderCatalogOnServer",
               layout: "pdf",
               page_size: "Letter",
               margin: { :top => 0, :bottom => 0, :left => 0 , :right => 0}
      end
    end
  end
```

Active Job method that is adding a margin around each page:

```
class CreatePdfJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(catalog_id)
    //declaring variables here -- removing to condense question

    generatedPdf  = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
      ApplicationController.render(
        template: 'catalog/renderCatalogOnServer',
        layout: 'layouts/pdf',
        page_size: "Letter",
        margin: { :top => 0, :bottom => 0, :left => 0 , :right => 0},
        locals: { catalog: @catalog, business_units: @business_units, brands: @brands },
      )
    )

    overlay = Tempfile.new('overlay')
    overlay.binmode
    overlay.write(generatedPdf)
    overlay.close
    pdfPath = overlay.path # to get path

    catalog_record.pdf.attach(io: URI.open(pdfPath), filename: "#{@catalog.name}.pdf")
  end
end
```

I'm guessing it's in the way I'm having to call `ApplicationController.render`, or create a tempfile before saving. I'm looking for how to remove the margin from the PDF, but also welcome any feedback on a better way to produce the PDF with ActiveJob and WickedPDF. The way it's working now seems like overkill, but it's the only way I've found that actually generates a PDF (although with incorrect margins).

Thanks!

Comment: @engineersmnky omg... that was it. What you saw in 2 seconds, I couldn't see for 2 days lol. Feel free to add as an answer and I can mark as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are passing the PDF options to `ApplicationController#render` which is essentially just ignoring them (disposing of them) because that method does not know what those options are intended to do.

Instead you need to pass the PDF options to `WickedPdf#pdf_from_string` so that they can control how the PDF itself is generated.

To do this simply change:

```
 generatedPdf  = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
      ApplicationController.render(
        template: 'catalog/renderCatalogOnServer',
        layout: 'layouts/pdf',
        page_size: "Letter",
        margin: { :top => 0, :bottom => 0, :left => 0 , :right => 0},
        locals: { catalog: @catalog, business_units: @business_units, brands: @brands },
      )
    )
```

To:

```
 generatedPdf  = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
      ApplicationController.render(
        template: 'catalog/renderCatalogOnServer',
        layout: 'layouts/pdf',
        locals: { catalog: @catalog, business_units: @business_units, brands: @brands}
      ),  
      page_size: "Letter",
      margin: { :top => 0, :bottom => 0, :left => 0 , :right => 0}
    )
```

Comment: @enginerrsmnky thank you 